# Can Managers Make You Wear a Uniform?

Tags: management

I manage a care home and have never worn a uniform only a smart outfit -  suit / dress. The home managers for the organisation I work for have now told us that we have to wear a nurses uniform.

Can this be enforced?

Comment: @Jayne Mur This question really can't be answered because the employee's rules will change from one business to the next. You should really direct this question to HR. If you feel the requirement is illegal, you may want to consult an attourney.

Comment: Hi Jayne and welcome to The Workplace.  Questions about laws or company-specific policies are off-topic here, so I'm putting this on hold.  If your underlying question is "how can I avoid having to wear this newly-required uniform", please [edit] to ask that and we can review for re-opening.  Thanks for understanding.

Comment: It depends on so many things, so the only possible answer is **they could**

Answer (score 4):

> The home managers for the organisation I work for have now told us
>   that we have to wear a nurses uniform.
>
> Can this be enforced?

It's not clear what you mean by "enforced" here.

If you are asking "can you be fired for not wearing a required uniform?", the answer (at least in my locale) is "Yes".

A company can change its uniform requirements whenever they wish.

The presence of a union may alter the answer, and as HLGEM correctly points out, the laws in your particular locale might change the answer as well.

You could start by contacting your HR department (if you have one), and learn your particular company's rules and regulations regarding uniforms for your position.

Comment: This is a US centric answer. In other countries, you may need to check the labor laws.